# IF formula on time cell not working

Tags: excel-formula

```
IF(AND(H$2>=$B2,H$2<=$C2),"X","")
```

Works for **08:30-15:30** and **9:30-18:30**, but it does for shift **19:30-4:30** check the image (highlighted in yellow cell)

[image: Reference]

Comment: You are probably going to have to reformat this post.

Comment: Because of the `AND` condition. `20:00 >= 20:00 AND 19:30 <= 04:30` isn't true since the end is "before" 20:00 and not after.. It doesn't manage the change of day.

Comment: put `=AN2` somewhere and format the cell as a number. Is it 1.020833 or 0.020833? If the former then you need to change the series in D2:AZ2. Use `=TIME(6, 30, 0)` in D2 then `=MOD($D2+TIME(0, 30*COLUMN(A:A), 0), 1)` in E2 and drag E2 right.

Comment: Thanks fo the "=Time". The problem solves if i use =IF(OR(AD$2>=$B4,AD$2<=$C4),"X","") for 19:30-04:30 shift. But it cannot be used for 08:30-15:30 & 09:30-18:30. i.e I need to use two formula =IF(AND(H$2>=$B3,H$2<=$C3),"X","") / =IF(OR(H$2>=$B3,H$2<=$C3),"X",""). Is there any way to use a formula that works for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "simple" solution would be to check if `start` is bigger than `end`. In that case, you will need to check for

```
time >= start OR time <= end
```

Something like :

```
=IF(
    $B2<$C2;
        IF(AND(H$2>=$B2;H$2<=$C2);"X";"");
        IF(OR( H$2>=$B2;H$2<=$C2);"X";"")
)
```

Comment: Might be because I am using `;` instead of `,` (strange, version or locale difference I would guess) or because I adapt the column to match yours and made a mistake, but the condition is correct @Srk

Comment: I understand that this solution "works," but  I suspect both it and the original post need to change slightly.  For example, for the period 08:30-15:30, I would treat that as 7 hours (assuming no breaks).  The original diagram and the solution both translate this into 15 half-hour periods.  

I am not sure that breaks are possible, but is the 15 half-hour periods used because it is assumed that there is a half-hour break?  If so, would you not want to represent that somehow?

Comment: "_I am not sure that breaks are possible, but is the 15 half-hour periods used because it is assumed that there is a half-hour break? If so, would you not want to represent that somehow?_" My point is that I agree that the "end" should not be included, to reduce the ticked period to match the need. But the part about "break" is totally off topic here and I don't see why you want to include this.

Comment: In this: "I am not sure that breaks are possible, but is the 15 half-hour periods used because it is assumed that there is a half-hour break? If so, would you not want to represent that somehow?" I was asking (ineffectually) if somehow one of the 15 half hours did not count so that it would actually equal 7 hours.  Your explanation of these as tick marks makes my comment useless and worthy of deletion if we were not discussing it. I mistook those as half hours worked.

Comment: @AxelH, please forgive my error. I was directing it as a response to his comment that it works and left out the reference. It was never intended to critique your solution. I was trying to understand what was being represented.

Answer (score 0):

Better to include date part into your formula of each cell showing time and re-format these cells to show the time part only. They include:
1. Start and end for each resource: For example, for `B3`, make it as "`2018-07-02 08:30`" and format it as "`hh:mm`";
2. Time marker in the header in the second row, i.e. for `D2`, `E2`, ..., sets up `D2` as the starting point to include the date part as well, then sets cells after it increase 30 minuets from each previous cell. That is, sets `E2` as `=D2+TIME(0,30,0)`, and copy `E2` right. Also re-format all these cells as "hh:mm";
3. Date marker in the header in first row, i.e. for `D1`, `AM1`, ..., let `D1` as `=D2` and format as date (and merge cells of course) , then copy right.
In this way, the formula should work and the cells' format looks same.