# Count cell logically in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Hi want to count cell logically according to given value. That means it counts the number of X in a particular range with a specified value. Please check the attachment for better understanding. For now i have achieved it using

```
=IF(F3="X",$D3,"")
```

but it needs to give the count in a specific value.

[image: ref 1]

How can I add another condition to `IF()` that will stop putting P1 after the hrs  value from Cell E3? (10 cells as this is half hourly).

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238467/if-formula-on-time-cell-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also a bit confused by the image and comments.  You ask about counts (which could be somewhat easy using COUNTIF or COUNTIFS), but then seem to want to place values in cells (and possibly highlight them in yellow) unless they are outside the number of hours allotted to a job.

I am responding to this portion only:  "How can I add another condition to IF() that will stop putting P1 after the hrs value from Cell E3? (10 cells as this is half hourly)."

You only are asking what you add to this:

```
=IF(F3="X",$D3,"")
```

which is rather hard to answer since my answer would be:

> Add AND( after the first parenthesis and prior to the F3="X" and then put
>   COUNTIF($F3:F3,"X")<=INT($E3*2)), after the first comma and before the $D3 in your original formula

which is possibly the most unhelpful way I could answer this (honestly, I am not even sure I have that worded correctly).

I would prefer to offer this instead:  Please put this formula in Cell F4:

```
=IF(AND(F3="X",COUNTIF($F3:F3,"X")<=INT($E3*2)),$D3,"")
```

This would then be copied to the remaining cells to the right of that cell.  Even though the request was specific to the row with information based on E3, I made the formula somewhat generic so that it could be used for all three rows (the rows starting in F4, F6, and F8).  I am using the INT function because I have no idea what limits the data are for the number of hours and wanted to compare to a whole number.  You may want to eliminate that or use a rounding function instead.

I realize your chart is a work in progress, so as you add rows and columns, you made need to adjust this formula to fit those changes, but that should be a bit more straightforward.

I hope this offers some assistance.

I am adding some additional information based on the comments received and assuming that there will be up to three additional jobs and hours for each resource adding a maximum of 6 extra columns before the first column with "X"es.  Doing this complicates the formula.  This formula will work for codes up to and including 9 characters.  The code in cell L4 (which used to be F4) now becomes:

```
=IFERROR(IF(L3="X",TRIM(MID(REPT(LEFT($D3&REPT(" ",9),9),$E3*2)&REPT(LEFT($F3&REPT(" ",9),9),$G3*2)&REPT(LEFT($H3&REPT(" ",9),9),$I3*2)&REPT(LEFT($J3&REPT(" ",9),9),$K3*2),COUNTIF($L3:L3,"X")*9-8,9)),""),"")
```

What this does is create a string of values based on the jobs and half-hours and then picks the appropriate code from that list based on the count of "X"es that have occurred as of the current column.

An image of what I created to test this is attached.  Hopefully you can make any additional changes from here.
[image]

Just an aside, I multiplied the hours by 2 to get the number of half hours and did not use INT() or ROUND() or some other method of getting whole numbers because it is unclear what rules we are using for fractions of an hour and the original spreadsheet uploaded does not accommodate such scenarios.  If the smallest fraction of an hour is .5, this solution should work fine.  However, if you have smaller fractions, it may not work as desired since the REPT function I use will automatically truncate such that if someone has 5.49 hours, there will be 10 entries but if someone has 5.50 there will be 11.

Comment: Yes! this formula works perfectly as wanted. Sorry! for the question that was not so clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Further to this output. If I add new columns "F" & "G". In cell F3 value "P4" & Cell G3 value "4.0". Modifying the current formula  =IF(AND(F3="X",COUNTIF($F3:F3,"X")<=INT($E3*2)),$D3,"") can I get result "P4" in row BF4:BI4

Comment: It will not be as easy as copying the formula over.  I think you need to organize how you want this to look.  The original design has each individual working for a large number of hours but then allocates it to a single project.  Think about things like:  If there are multiple projects, do you want to add a row for each or additional columns for each? It may be easier to add rows but not as aesthetically pleasing. Is there a maximum number of projects?  The original design assumed one. Now there are two.  Will there be 3? 4? A fixed number will be simpler than "N" projects. What is the goal?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes there will be Max 4 number of projects (column) for one resource, not more than that. The problem with adding row for multiple project is that the result "P4" will start from column "H". i.e one resource working on multiple project at a time. So the idea is that second project "P4" starts from the the end of first project "P1" and so on for third & fourth..

Comment: I am a bit confused now. P1 ended in O4 and your comment from a few hours ago said you wanted P4 to begin in column BF and go for only four columns to BI. If I understand your current statement, you want P4 to begin in column H. 
However, based on the original post, the next "X"ed column which would be column P.  Do you want it to begin in H or BF and why not P?  How would I know when it begins? Also, if it is 4.0 hours, wouldn't you want it to use 8 cells? I apologize for being confused. I need to think about a solution either way, but I want to clarify this point before I look at it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry! Its me who confused you using the wrong reference. Please ignore the 2 comment. Yes you are right P1 ends in O4 and i.e 5hrs 10 cells. Adding a column F & G with new input "P4" in cell F3 & input 4 hrs in G3. Now "P1" ends at Q4 from O4, due to adding of 2 columns. Now the "P4" should display from R4:Y4 considering it is 4 hrs (8 cells). All in one row (row 4). I will add more columns max 4 jobs per resource.

Comment: I am adding some information to my response in the hopes that it helps you.

Seriously, it would have helped to know there were four project/hour combinations before posting my answer.  What I am doing is assuming that there are four pairs of Project/Hours in D/E, F/G, H/I, and JK.  Please note that the response I post may not be particularly valid if you add additional rows or change the size of the project values significantly.

Comment: I am now understanding your comment about P4 beginning in column H.  If there were multiple rows for each project, I think you were meaning it would have begun in column F.  That could have easily been avoided so that the starting column would have been the first column not previously filled for that resource.  Not a big deal, but doing that it would have been easier to have a variable number of projects.

Comment: Somehow I thought I saw a comment extending the size of the code to 9 characters which no longer appears.  The above answer has a revised formula to handle 9 character codes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your issue, you can try this formula in K4, and pull it to the right and left side.

The formula will check if there is an X in the cell above and then if there are less 10 X in a row and returns "P1". I added the iferror because of the REF error that you would get if you go too much on the left

```
=IF(K3="X",IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(A3:J3,"X")<10,"P1",""),"P1"),"")
```

Comment: Sorry! It did not help. Actually the below formula somewhat comes closer. =IF($B3<$C3,IF(AND(F$2>=$B3+TIME($E3,0,0),F$2<=$C3),"",$D3),IF(OR( F$2>=$B3+TIME($E3,0,0),F$2<=$C3),"",$D3)) but the "P1"  appears from row "Y4" onwards.